# VBA Worksheet_SelectionChange not working

Tags: vba, excel

My VBA is a bit rusty so I am having trouble building an application that automatically updates some cells when the value of a cell is modified.

I've started with this basic subroutine, located on a `Worksheet` page:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Application.EnableEvents = True
If Not Intersect(Target, Target.Worksheet.Range("A1")) Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "Lorem Ipsum"
End If

End Sub
```

This subroutine should pop-up a message box *Lorem Ipsum* when cell A1's value is modified.

However this is not working. I've been unable to find where is the issue; typical problems (subroutine located in a module, `EnableEvents` turned `False`) should not happen with the code above; I've also tried to change `Target.Worksheet.Range("A1")` to `Range("A1")`.

Does anyone know where is the issue coming from?

Comment: It works fine for me

Comment: Can you doubly ensure that it is in the right sheet code area?

Comment: And then type `Application.EnableEvents = True` in the Immediate Window and then check

Comment: Ok, that worked (the "`Application.EnableEvents = True` in the immediate window" comment), thank you for the immediate window tip.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that when `Application.EnableEvents` are off, the Worksheet Events don't fire and your code will not get a chance to run.

To turn it back on, type `Application.EnableEvents = True` in the Immediate Window as shown below

[image]

Now your code should run without any problems.

Comment: The first line of my code (`Application.EnableEvents = True`) should handle that, shouldn't it?

Comment: If `Application.EnableEvents = False` then the event will not fire and the code will never have been ran in the first place.

Comment: Thomas, you are in the right track. However you need to add one more line to explain how to switch it on :)

Comment: @DaneelOlivaw: See my last comment under your question ;)

Comment: @SiddharthRout I tried to clarify my answer it's still missing something.   I'm just not sure how to expand upon it and stay on topic. Thanks for your input.

Comment: I have edited your answer. If you do not like it, feel free to revert it :)

Comment: That is what I mentioned in comments below the question. OP confirmed that this was the issue :)

Comment: Very nice I seen that after I you commented to me, but wasn't sure if I should incorporate it into my answer.  Thanks again.

Answer (score -1):

I copied your code and it worked as one should expect. Note though that you need to *manually* edit cell A1 on the *worksheet where the code is* to get up the MsgBox.  [Recalculation has no bite on the worksheet change event.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839775.aspx)

Comment: You are going off track :)